# Class containing a List of a generically Typed Class

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a generic class, `JSTable`, that takes a type RowType. I want to have a class that can contain many `JSTables`, each with a different RowType, so that I may do something like the `Func<>` in `C#` does, where it has many optional types. Is this only possible because there are many representations of `Func<>`? I want a limitless option, so that I could potentially declare a `JSGridVM` with hundreds of tables, or one table.

```
public class JSGridVM<?>//where ? is as many types as I want
{
    public List<JSTable<?>> Tables { get; set; };
}

public class JSTable<RowType>
{
    public JSTable() { }
    public JSTable(List<RowType> rows, List<JSGridColumn> columns, bool allowEditingRows, bool allowDeletingRows, string updateURL, string deleteURL)
    {
        Rows = rows;
        Columns = columns;

        AllowEditingRows = allowEditingRows;
        AllowDeletingRows = allowDeletingRows;
        UpdateURL = updateURL;
        DeleteURL = deleteURL;
    }

    public List<RowType> Rows { get; set; }
    public List<JSGridColumn> Columns { get; set; }

    public bool AllowEditingRows { get; set; }
    public bool AllowDeletingRows { get; set; }
    public string UpdateURL { get; set; }
    public string DeleteURL { get; set; }
}

public class JSGridColumn
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public ColumnType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum ColumnType
{
    Text,
    Hidden,
}
```

Then declare like

```
var jsGridVM = new JSGridVM<SomeClass1, SomeClass2, SomeClass3>();
```

OR

```
var jsGridVM = new JSGridVM<SomeClass1>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare generic type argument `<RowType>` not at `class` level, but at methods: `AddTable` and `GetTable`:

```
public class JSGridVM
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> Tables = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public JSGridVM AddJSTable<RowType>()
    {
        Tables.Add(typeof(RowType), new JSTable<RowType>());
        return this;
    }

    public JSTable<RowType> GetJSTable<RowType>()
    {
        Tables.TryGetValue(typeof(RowType), out object temp);
        return (JSTable<RowType>)temp;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var sample = new JSGridVM();
sample.AddJSTable<RowTypeA>().AddJSTable<RowTypeB>();
var test = a.GetJSTable<RowTypeA>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own class, but the .NET DataSet class might be what you are after.  DataSet has been around for ages and is still pretty useful.

```
        var ds = new DataSet();

        var dataTable = new DataTable("DataTable");
        var stringCol = new DataColumn("String Column", typeof(string));
        var intCol = new DataColumn("Integer Column", typeof(int));
        var decimalCol = new DataColumn("Decimal Column", typeof(decimal));

        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new [] {stringCol, intCol, decimalCol});
        var newRow = new object[]
        {
            "String item",
            1,
            100.08m
        };
        dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

        ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        var row = ds.Tables["DataTable"].Rows[0];
        var stringRowValue = row["String Column"];
        var intRowValue = row["Integer Column"];
        var decimalRowValue = row["Decimal Column"];
        Console.WriteLine($"String value: {stringRowValue}\nInteger value: {intRowValue}\nDecimal Value: {decimalRowValue}");

        var rowArr = new DataRow[ds.Tables["DataTable"].Rows.Count];
        ds.Tables["DataTable"].Rows.CopyTo(rowArr, 0);

        var list = rowArr.ToList();

        foreach (DataRow rowitem in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nFrom List: String value: {rowitem["String Column"]}\nInteger value: {rowitem["String Column"]}\nDecimal Value: {rowitem["String Column"]}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this is already pretty robust.  If you are trying to accomplish a specific use case by creating a generic class, then check out MSDN for more help.

Using Generics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters

Func:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not :

```
public class JSGridVM<JSTable>
{
    public List<JSTable> Tables { get; set; };
}

public class JSTable<?>
{

}

var rowTypeAnimals = AnimalRowType();
var rowTypeBirds = BirdRowType();

var animalTable = new JSTable<AnimalRowType>(){rowTypeAnimals };
var birdTable = new JSTable<BirdRowType>(){rowTypeBirds };

var grid = new JSGridVM(){animalTable,birdTable};
```

Keep the row type generic for your table and your grid will always have the same JSTable type.

Comment: This solution doesn't work because you cannot declare an instance of JSGridVM without the type JSTable, which will require the row type. Therefore you end up with the same problem